# Google Says I'm Not Caching Even Though I Am?

Tags: .htaccess, caching

Google's Pagespeed Insights ( https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ ) is saying that I'm not leveraging browser caching. However, I previously checked if I'm caching at seositecheck ( http://seositecheckup.com/tool/x_cache_header ) and the results said I was indeed leveraging browser caching. So how can I get Google to notice this?

Here's my htaccess code:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 64 days"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! It's because of an external reference in my JS file! //google-analytics.com/analytics.js Because it's an external file, it can't be cached by my site. I understand I could store this file on my own site, but I think that might be more hassle than it's worth. You'd have to keep up to date with changes to the file, which you can do with PHP, but it still seems a bit too much effort for something so small. On the chance anyone reads this and is curious how to store and auto-update Google Analytics (or really any page for that matter), I found a great guide here: http://diywpblog.com/leverage-browser-cache-optimize-google-analytics/